# NSManagedObject not going into Model

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am using the following code to try and upload a NSManagedObject in the model (possibly incorrect term).

Please could you tell me what the problem is.

```
CDImage *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [image setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [image setImage:UIImagePNGRepresentation([_imageView image])];
    [image setLocation:[dict objectForKey:@"location"]];
    [image setUrl:[dict objectForKey:@"url"]];
```

CDImage.m

```
@synthesize url, date, image, location;
- (void) dealloc {
    [url release];
    [date release];
    [image release];
    [location release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

My Model:

[image]

Getting the objects:

```
- (void) refreshArray {
    if ([[self cdArray] isEqual:nil]) {
        [self setCdArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    }
    [cdArray removeAllObjects];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];    
    for (CDImage *image in fetchedObjects) {
        [cdArray addObject:image];
        [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[cdArray indexOfObject:image] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    }
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%d", [cdArray count]);
    NSLog(@"IN REFRESH ARRAY");
    [fetchRequest release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the context after writing

```
NSError *saveError;        
if (![context save:&saveError]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving entity: %@", saveError);
}
```